# How do I convert a string to an int variable in BizTalk XLANG?

Tags: xpath, biztalk

I have the following XPath expression which assigns a value from a file however it comes as a string, and I need to convert to an int variable in XLANG but now sure the syntax

```
nrOfRecordsstr= xpath(CaseIn,"/*[local-name()='CaseFile' and namespace-uri()='http://xx.com/casefile']/*[local-name()='Header' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='NrofRecords' and namespace-uri()='']");

nrofRecorsint=??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.Convert.ToInt32(string s);

```
nrOfRecordsstr = xpath(CaseIn,"/*[local-name()='CaseFile' and namespace-uri()='http://xx.com/casefile']/*[local-name()='Header' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='NrofRecords' and namespace-uri()='']");
nrofRecorsint = System.Convert.ToInt32(nrOfRecordsstr);
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to wrap that XPath in either `number()` or `string()` - in some cases XLANGs will end up returning a node and you'll get exceptions saying it doesn't know how to convert a node to an Int32.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about BizTalk, but in XPath you can use `number()` function to return number instead of string. So, assuming your initial XPath expression return singular value, you can start by wrapping it with `number()`, something like this :

```
number(/*[local-name()='CaseFile' and namespace-uri()='http://xx.com/casefile']/....)
```

Comment: This is good practice for BizTalk, as it prevents confusion - still need the `System.Convert` call though to change it to the CLR type in XLANGs.

Comment: @DanField Works without `System.Convert` for me. Like this:
    `IntVariable = xpath(MyMessage, "number(...)")`

Comment: Good to know @OlegDeribas